# client/server approach in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am wondering if something as basic as client/server operation model is easily doable with Meteor (meteor.com) framework.

A primitive template should

```html
<template name="input">
  <div>
    <input type="text" val="">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</template>

<template name="output">
  <div id="output">
  </div>
</template>
```

wait for input, calls a server to execute `serverFunction()` on the input's value, and insert the result into the output tag.  No collections, mongo, or authentication required.  Of course, every client is supposed to receive its own results. It seems that `Meteor.publish()` operates only on collections.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Methods section in Meteor documentation:
http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header

"Methods are remote functions that Meteor clients can invoke."

There's also code in the Wordplay example to show how to work this RPC mechanism (see the definition of Meteor.methods({ ... }) in model.js and game.js in this example project for more info).

Comment: `Meteor.methods` work, but the examples still rely on creating Collections to differentiate between connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

a Meteor Collection is only associated with a Mongo collection if you tell it to be.. you can also use them to wrap arbitrary data.

The three main benefits of Meteor Collections (for me, at least):

1. the publish / subscribe model for keeping server and client data in sync
2. they can wrap persisted (Mongo) or arbitrary data
3. the ability to query them with Mongo-like syntax

Comment: The docs state that a Collection is always tied to mongo once I name it, otherwise it's not synchronized.

Comment: where does it say that? I publish (synchronise) Collections that are not persisted in Mongo regularly..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

server:

```
Meteor.methods = 
  doStuff: (input) ->
    serverFunction input
```

client:

```coffeescript
Template.input.events =
  'submit': ->
    Meteor.call 'doStuff', $('input[type=text]').val(), (error, result) -›
      Session.set 'result', result

Template.output.output = ->
  Session.get 'result
```